# Printing array contents as string

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm working on some JavaScript validation and need a way to print out error messages.

I have an array called `errorList` and I have a div which I would like to print the array contents out into, called `divErrorList`.

I have a function which adds the error to the array:

```
errorList[errorList.length] = errorArray;
```

So now I want to print `errorList` out, perhaps using `innerHTML` ?

Although I have tried this, and I don't get an error but I do not see the error list being printed either.

```
document.getElementById("divErrorList").innerHTML+=(errorList[i]);
```

Comment: can u share the whole code?...i dont think anything is wrong here

Comment: Well, what is `i` in `errorList[i]`? Perhaps you want to do `errorlist.join(', ')`. If you want to add just the latest error, then `innerHTML += errorList[errorList.length-1]`.

Comment: where have you defined i ?

Comment: You're adding `errorArray` to your error list, you cannot just print each array. Try `....innerHTML+=errorList[i].join(', ');`

Comment: You should use `errorList.push(errorArray);` instead of the first line

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't want to post your essential code, I'm going to assume `errorArray` is... an array?

So errorList would be an array of arrays? Then you need a nested loop, or to join each error like so:

```
var errorList = [
    ['error 1.1', 'error 1.2'],
    ['error 2.1'],
    ['error 3.1', 'error 3.2', 'error 3.3'],
    ['error 4.1', 'error 4.2']
];

var errorString = "";

// for each errorArray
for(var i=0, len=errorList.length; i<len; i++){
    // join the errorArray
    errorString += '<h1>ErrorArray #'+ i +'</h1>'
    +'<ul><li>'+ errorList[i].join('</li><li>') +'</li></ul>';
}

document.body.innerHTML = errorString;
```

### JS Fiddle Demo

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to populate an array with errors is the following:

Assign to your elements a `data-validate` and a `data-error` attribute:

```
<form name="myForm">
  * Name
  <input name=Name data-validate=text data-error="Name cannot be empty"> <br>
  * Email
  <input name=Email data-validate=email data-error="Invalid Email"> <br>
  * Message
  <textarea name=Message data-validate=text data-error="Enter a Message">
  </textarea> <br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>

<div id="divErrorList"></div>
```

Than cache your selectors:

```
var myForm = document.forms.myForm;
var divError = document.getElementById("divErrorList");
```

than create an Object that will contain all the needed validate methods:

```
var validator = {
  text  : function(val) { return !/^\s*\S+.*/.test(val); },
  email : function(val) { return !/\S+@\S+\.\S+/.test(val); }
};
```

<sup>(You can additionally improve the regexes above)</sup>

Once you `submit` your Form, you check all your Form Elements with `this.elements` and after you make sure one has a `data-validate`, you simply call your respective validate method for that field Value.

If your validate method returns `true` means that a certain field did not passed the test, so you can move on and `.push()` into an `errors` Array the message stored in that element's `data-error` attribute:

```
function validateForm(event) {
  var errors = [];
  var el = this.elements;
  for(var i=0; i<el.length; i++){
    var data = el[i].dataset;
    var validateType  = data.validate;
    var validateError = data.error;
    if(validateType){ // "text", "email", ...
        if(validator[validateType](el[i].value)) errors.push( validateError );
    }
  }
  // Check for errors length and write to DIV...*
}

myForm.onsubmit = validateForm;
```

(*)Than, (always inside the same function) you simply check for the `errors` Array length and if there's some errors you can write your errors to your element by joining the Array keys with `<br>` (for example)

```
  if(errors.length){
    event.preventDefault();
    divError.innerHTML = errors.join("<br>");
  }
```

```js
var myForm = document.forms.myForm;
var divError = document.getElementById("divErrorList");

var validator = {
  text  : function(val) { return !/^\s*\S+.*/.test(val); },
  email : function(val) { return !/\S+@\S+\.\S+/.test(val); }
};

function validateForm(event) {
  var errors = [];
  var el = this.elements;
  for(var i=0; i<el.length; i++){
   var data = el[i].dataset;
   var validateType  = data.validate;
   var validateError = data.error;
    if(validateType){ // "text", "email", ...
     if(validator[validateType](el[i].value)) errors.push( validateError );
    }
  }
  if(errors.length){
    event.preventDefault();
    divError.innerHTML = errors.join("<br>");
  }
}

myForm.onsubmit = validateForm;
```

```html
<form name="myForm">
  * Name
  <input name=Name data-validate=text data-error="Name cannot be empty"> <br>
  * Email
  <input name=Email data-validate=email data-error="Invalid Email"> <br>
  * Message
  <textarea name=Message data-validate=text data-error="Enter a Message">
  </textarea> <br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>

<div id="divErrorList"></div>
```